# I am getting an error while retrieving data by using an HTTP GET request

Tags: android

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {


    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=7000;
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT=15000;
    public String type,username,password,url;
    public HttpURLConnection con;
    public StringBuilder stringBuilder;
    public InputStream input;
    public BufferedReader reader;
    public URL myURL;
    public ProgressDialog pdLoading;
    public AlertDialog alertDialog;
    public Context context;
    BackgroundWorker(Context ctxt){
        context = ctxt;
        con = null;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        this.type = params[0];
        this.url = params[1];
        this.username = params[2];
        this.password = params[3];

        if (this.type == "POST")
        {
          // here iam handle post request
        }
        if (this.type == "GET")
        {

            try {
                this.myURL = new URL(this.url);
                this.con =(HttpURLConnection) this.myURL.openConnection();
                this.con.setRequestMethod(this.type);
                this.con.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                this.con.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                this.con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                this.con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                this.con.connect();

                this.input = this.con.getInputStream();
                this.reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input,"UTF-8"),8);
                stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String inputLine;
                while((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
                }
                reader.close();
                return this.con.toString();
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
   // compiler found in catch block when iam perform get request event
                return String.format("The url %s\n%s\n%s",e.getMessage(),this.type,this.url);
            } finally {
                this.con.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: did you hit the same web service to post man and checked the response first

Comment: show your error log

Comment: You posted only code. There is no text explaining what you want or what you do. There is no problem description. There is no question. Please write a normal decent post first.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see any Get parameteres appending with your web service. This must be the reason. You need to send parameters with your requrest. Below is the code taken from your code

```
 this.type = params[0];
    this.url = params[1];
    this.username = params[2];
    this.password = params[3];
```

You are not sending these params with your web service.

Comment: String type = "GET";
        String url = "http://7eb128fa.ngrok.io/courses";
        BackgroundWorker bW = new BackgroundWorker(Dashboard.this);
        bW.execute(type,url,"","");

Comment: the parameter comes from here

Comment: I know where the parameters are coming from but you are sending those params with your webservice